# Navigation to a route within Nuxt.js Universal app, causes errors. Using Contentful headless cms

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I am currently trying to generate the routes and this is returning with just the home at the moment.

`When I go to website.com/work/_slug` = Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Here is my generate routes code, I am using contentful

```js
generate: {
      routes: async function () {
        const entries = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "Project" });
        const routes = []
        entries.items.forEach(item => {
          routes.push(`/work/${item.fields.slug}`)
        })
        return routes
      }
    },
```